# Facebook SDK 3.0 Android get AccessToken for saved user with id and password?

Tags: android, facebook, passwords, access-token, userid

Is it possible to get a AccessToken for android Facebook API call with saved User id and password?

Or maybe get AccessToken for android from Facebook Websites or some other ways...

I do have User Id and Password!!

**Not using facebook login UI!!**

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT DO THIS!

Facebook Platform Policy explicitly prohibits you from collecting user name and passwords (see https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ section I.2). If you do this, your app will get shut down.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Accees token specific to your application you need to create App on [facebook developers accout](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and then you will get Access token 
when you use your saved login you wont have access to that URls that isuse to regiter App and return Access token